# Custom SOPC Builder Components in Quartus II

Tags: quartus-ii

I am trying to understand how to interface with a custom component within SOPC builder. Basically I have a verilog module which creates and outputs a tone to the audio out line on an Altera DE2 development board. I want to interface with this module in SOPC builder so I can control it using C code and the NIOS II processor.

What I am having trouble understanding is the setting of signals when creating a custom component in SOPC builder. I can successfully add my .v files into the component and it gives me a list of top level signals which I need to set to certain values. I am not sure what to set the signals, such as my GPIO and AUD_ADCLRCK, to within the create custom component. All I really want to do is pass a value to my audio module telling it what frequency to output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check Avalon-MM and Avalon-ST specifications here: http://www.altera.com/literature/manual/mnl_avalon_spec.pdf. You'll also find all the timing diagrams in this PDF file. Usually, the control interface is done using Avalon-MM interface, which has 32bit read and write data ports, plus 32bit address, plus control signals and IRQ if needed. Avalon-ST is used for streaming devices, so You can use it for Audio.